# Trying to get the value of this parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the value from `theTime` into `Timeout` but it seems that when I use `@a_bar` it doesn't pick up the values. What should be the fix?

```
if (logOut == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    try 
    {
        string theTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.Add("@a_bar", OleDbType.Date).Value = theTime;
        string query = "update MTR set Timeout = '@a_bar'  where Stamp = '" + label9.Text + "'";
        MessageBox.Show(query);
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: `'@a_bar'` is the string literal "@a_bar", not a parameter reference. Remove the apostrophes.

Comment: You're completely misusing parameters; your query should be `update MTR set Timeout = @a_bar where Stamp = @stamp` with no aposotropes, and you need to define `@stamp` as well.

Comment: Also: set the value of @a_bar as the DateTime value, not a string